# Using a inferred type, which is a valid key type, as the name of a property in a computed interface

Tags: typescript, generics

I currently have this:

```
export class UnderTest<N extends string> {
  name: N;
}

export type Tester<T> =
  T extends UnderTest<infer N>
    ? { name: `${N}`, passed: true }
    : { passed: false };

let x: Tester<Object>;
let y: Tester<UnderTest<"foo">>;
```

Which is doing what expected, that is, creating 2 variables of two different types, where the first type is `{ passed: false }` and the second type is `{ name: "foo", passed: true }`.

I would like to know whether **it is possible to alter the *"passed"* case to include a property named after N**. Basically, I would like for `Tester<T>` to do this.

```
export type Tester<T> =
  T extends UnderTest<infer N>
    ? { name: `${N}`, passed: true, `${N}`: "Yes, baby!" }
    : { passed: false };
```

So that `y: Tester<UnderTest<"foo">>` would have a `foo: "Yes, baby!"` property. As of Version 4.8.4, the declaration above triggers a few errors.

```
esri/views/shadergraph/v6.ts:59:41 - error TS1131: Property or signature expected.

59         ? { name: `${N}`, passed: true, `${N}`: "Yes, baby!" }
                                       ~~~

esri/views/shadergraph/v6.ts:59:47 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

59         ? { name: `${N}`, passed: true, `${N}`: "Yes, baby!" }
                                             ~

esri/views/shadergraph/v6.ts:59:62 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

59         ? { name: `${N}`, passed: true, `${N}`: "Yes, baby!" }
                                                            ~

esri/views/shadergraph/v6.ts:60:9 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

60         : { passed: false };
       ~

[12:35:38 PM] Found 4 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersect it with a mapped type:

```
? { name: `${N}`, passed: true } & { [_ in N]: "Yes, baby!" }
```

You might also have to add an infer constraint if this gives an error about N not being a property key:

```
T extends UnderTest<infer N extends string>
```

Since this mapped type only has one key and one value, we could also use `Record` to achieve the same thing:

```
? { name: `${N}`, passed: true } & Record<N, "Yes, baby!">
```

Comment: Right! Awesome thank you! I am new to mapped types (learned about them yesterday morning) and didn't think about using `_ in N` where N is an inferred type. Thanks!