# How to declare type/interface with dynamic props

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I'm trying to type an interface (or type) with the following logic:

```js
interface MyArgs<Name, Id> {
  items: {
    [Name]: string,
    [Id]: string
  }[];
  idKey: string;
  nameKey: string;
}
```

In more detail:

I'm getting an array of items of an unknown type/interface (it's dynamic, they can be anything). While I could just type them as `any[]`, I'd like to know if it's possible to be a bit more specific about their type, and pass Typescript the information that I do have:

each item will be having an id property (e.g: `guid`, `id`, `uuid`) and a name property (e.g: `name`, `label`, `title`). The exact `idKey` and `nameKey` are provided as arguments (`idKey`, `nameKey`).

I want to declare the values provided in `idKey` and `nameKey` as valid keys for `items` records (e.g:  `{ [idKey]: string; [nameKey]: string }`(

What I tried above doesn't work. I also tried this:

```js
interface MyArgs<Name, Id> {
  items: { <Name>: string; <Id> : string }[]
  idKey: string
  nameKey: string
}
```

which is, too, invalid.

How can I achieve this?

Note: if the above would be possible without having to type the values twice (once inside `<>` and once in the values of `idKey` and `nameKey`, that would be even more awesome).

Comment: If the keys are as you said - dynamic, then how do you expect Typescript to know them during compile time?

Comment: @Mke, I want typescript to treat them as variables. It shouldn't care about their actual value, but it should know that `item[idKey]` is a `string` and so is `item[nameKey]`, without me having to declare `as string`.

Comment: [Does this give you any pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73965540/using-a-inferred-type-which-is-a-valid-key-type-as-the-name-of-a-property-in-a/73965568#73965568)

Comment: @caTS, probably, although I don't fully understand it, I'll play with it. Thanks!

Comment: @caTS, It's clear to me that `infer` is the right way to do it, but the implementation details for my specific case elude me (I keep getting errors). I'd appreciate an answer if you happen to know how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersect mapped types (or rather, Records) to create the correct object type:

```
interface MyArgs<Name extends string, Id extends string> {
  items: (
    { [_ in Name]: string; } &
    { [_ in Id]: string; }
  )[];
  idKey: string;
  nameKey: string;
}
```

If you need to, you can also constrain `Name` and `Id` to more specific keys:

```
interface MyArgs<Name extends "name" | "label" | "title", Id extends "guid" | "id" | "uuid"> {
```

---

You could also use Records to simplify it further:

```
  items: (
    Record<Name, string> & Record<Id, string>
  )[];
```

Or even just:

```
  items: Record<Id | Name, string>[];
```

Comment: With both syntaxes above I'm getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzseF.png). I'm using `"typescript": "~4.4.0"` (installed: `4.4.4`). Do I need a higher version?

Comment: Ah no, you just need to add a generic constraint. Probably `Name extends string` and `Id extends string`.

Comment: Awesome, works [like a charm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqYs7.png). But I don't really understand how I could have reached this result using the question you pinpointed as similar.

Comment: I used mapped types to create dynamically named keys. The focus in the linked question was this and not the usage of infer. Sorry if it was a little misleading :)

Comment: I'd like to fully understand your answer. I don't get why I should use `[_ in Name]: string` instead of `[Name]: string`. Isn't [in](https://learntypescript.dev/07/l5-in-type-guard) returning a boolean? Why is it used here? Could you update your answer with links to spec?

Comment: This is called a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html). Like "typeof" and "extends", TypeScript has repurposed this keyword when used in a different context.

Comment: Got it. So the most contrived version of what I need would be: `items: (Record<Id | Name, string> & Record<string, unknown>)[]`, which is shorter than `items: ({ [_ in Name | Id ]: string } & Record<string, unknown>)[]` by 4 chars. As far as I'm concerned, it's also more understandable. Much appreciated. Happy coding!

Comment: Sure, I did not realize I could do `Record<Id | Name, string>` :)